# How to change login name of user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, active-directory

I want to change in my .NET application login of user from Active Directory.

I'm changing it in this way now:

```
DirectoryEntry userToUpdate = updatedUser.GetDirectoryEntry();  
userToUpdate.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = user.NewLogin;  
userToUpdate.CommitChanges();
```

But it doesn't work as I expect. When I'm checking in AD "Active Directory Users and Computers" entry for this user then on tab "account" I see that:
- "User logon name" property isn't updated
- "User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)" property is correcly updated.

How to update correctly login name in AD from C# code? What property should I set in DirectoryEntry, or there is another method to change login name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two logon names in AD:

```
sAMAccountName    = User logon name, (pre-windows 2000) 
    Format/Usage: domain\user.name (note, your code will only populate user.name)

userPrincipalName = User logon name
    Format/Usage: user.name@domain.local
```

You need to update both.

Comment: sAMAccountName doesn't include the domain.

Comment: Correct, but when you login you must type `domain\user` (some apps put in the `domain\` for you. I updated to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try `userPrincipalName` instead of `sAMAccountName`.

Comment: Change both if you want to change both.  Change one if you want to change one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good link that you can reference be sure to checkout the bottom of the page to see it's full usage

[Everything in Active Directory via C#.Net 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/)

Comment: Huh? This user is trying to update an account, not find it. Also, his post is tagged .net-3.5... not v4.0