# Cannot update systemuser.domainname in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

In MS Dynamic CRM, I am trying to update systemuser.domainname using web services, but it is invalid for update. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For on premise CRM system the systemuser.domainname is resolved from Active Directory, once the user is created (this is in case if it is not integrated with Office 365). If this username is not found in AD you cannot create a user in CRM. So, in order to change the domainname through code, you should firstly change change the username in Active.

Check out the the following KB article from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930853

In order to change the AD username through code, you can check out the following answer,

[How to change login name of user in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466909/how-to-change-login-name-of-user-in-active-directory][2])

and then try to change it in CRM through your services.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc154894.aspx) this field cannot be updated. The documentation is for CRM 4.0 but I believe this hasn't changed in CRM 2011. There are also some constraints - e.g. domainname has to exist in the Active Directory and must not be used by any other CRM user.

```
Valid for update = False
```

I would consider deleting the original user and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the domainname field of a systemuser record is supported in CRM.

However the new domainname must successfully match to a user record in Active Directory. If it doesn't, CRM will throw and error and not allow the record to be saved.